# How to catch wheel click scroll thingie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mouseevent

You guys know this thing?

[image]

Is there anyway to put a listener on a div to try and catch it **on a div with overflow: hidden; set**? It looks like Facebook is doing it here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to catch it with just the [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event for jQuery?

[Seems to work](http://jsbin.com/aholag/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: Can you bind .scroll to an element or does it have to be on the document?

Comment: @Kirk According to the jQuery docs, you should be able to bind to elements as well. Just follow the first link in my answer (:

Comment: I updated my question to show a more specific case. Check this out as well: http://jsbin.com/aholag/3/edit

Comment: Hey so it turns out Facebook is using the 'scroll' event because they have overflow-y: auto and they are hiding the scroll bar.